# How do I get submission errors to display properly?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I'm setting up a registration form that uses [React Final Form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) to handle the form state. I have browser validation working great, but when I receive validation errors from the server I cannot figure out how to get them to display properly.

I've studied the [Submission Errors](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y9om95lyp) example that's included in the docs. I can't really see a significant difference from my code to that code. It seems that all that's needed is to return an object where the key is the field name and the value is the message to display.

Here's the method that's used for the Form `onSubmit` prop:

```
    async sendUserRequest(values) {
        try {
            const data = await axios.post('/register', {
                name:     `${values.firstName} ${values.lastName}`,
                email:    values.email,
                password: values.password
            });
        } catch (error) {
            let errors = {};
            Object.entries(error.response.data.errors).forEach(([field, value]) => {
                errors[field] = Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value;
            });

            console.log('errors', errors);
            return errors;
        }
    }
```

In the catch code I'm parsing out the errors in the object form I believe it's expecting. Here's an actual object that I'm returning:

```
{
  "email": "The email has already been taken."
}
```

I would expect this to display the message under the email field. As it is, it doesn't display anything.

Thank you for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that the example provided has some inconsistency that I kept focusing on.

[Here's a screenshot of the example code with what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7meq.png)

I updated my field prop to this and it worked:

```
error={meta.touched && ( meta.error || meta.submitError ) ? meta.error || meta.submitError : null}
```